# Can I run an air cleaner and air conditioner at the same time without a significant counter effect?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, air-quality, air-filter

Can this be counter effective, or the opposite?

I assume this also comes down to what I am using the air cleaner for, it is for dust allergies, but also vs air pollution.

I also guess that I need to let the air cleaner work on a higher airflow (higher setting) than the air conditioner for this to make more sense, but not sure how efficient will that be in terms of bringing air quality to a decent level and as far as air conditioning filters go, I have a Samsung AC with a cleanable mesh filters, but nothing more.

Comment: Is this air cleaner part of the heat/cool system and mounted in the duct work or is it a free standing unit? Is the A/C unit part of a whole house A/C system or a window type A/C? Need a better explanation of the Items you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry, I am a European and I guess we do not use a lot of other types for home use. I have a ductless Samsung AC, so it is an indoor unit with another outdoor unit part.

Comment: Could you describe the filter unit. Is it an electrostatic type, water bath or just pleated filters. I would run my filter when the AC is on because many AC units bring some external air in.

Comment: how would one affect the other?